# Is there an ISO code for animal reproduction method?

Tags: reproduction

Is there an ISO that can represent animals' reproduction method such as:

Oviparity, Ovoviviparous, Viviparous, and others?

Note: If the ISO term is not clear, here an example of an ISO: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but aren't ISO standards relating to created things. I believe there are terms defined, but not a specific standard for something that occurs naturally. You can also do a site search in google for example type (without quotes): "oviparous site:iso.org" into your search bar.

Comment: From the ISO website https://www.iso.org/developing-standards.html: "*ISO does not decide when to develop a new standard, but responds to a request from industry or other stakeholders such as consumer groups. Typically, an industry sector or group communicates the need for a standard to its national member who then contacts ISO.*" I can't think of anyone with both the financial incentive and resources to fund an effort to develop animal reproduction terminology.